# Jax ws Java Server with duplex binding - wcf client

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, jax-ws

I have been looking around for a solution to this for quite a while.
I have got a Java Jax WS server which is implemented in a Java environment. This server needs to get connected to a WCF client.
The problem now is that that client uses callbacks to achieve a bidirectional communication and cannot be modified.

Does anyone know if there is a duplex binding on the Java side to realize this communication?

WCF can establish a WSDualHttpBinding which is not compatible to JAX WS as far is I know.
I would be very thankfull for a solution to this.
Regards.

Comment: As a workaround solution to this problem I used client and server on each side combined with a message sequence buffer. This solution is not the cleanest but it works for me right now and provides secure traffic and a reliable message sequence.

On WCF side I think right now that a dual binding actually does the same in an integrated way.